# How to fix "AttributeError: Name of the index variable in the target entity or "instance_id" must be present in cutoff_time" error in featuretools?

Tags: python, featuretools

I have transactions and customers entities and my label and cutoff_time columns are in transactions entity where my target entity is customers. customers and transactions entities have relationship. How can I point my cutoff_time from customers entity?

I have created dataframe where 'customer_id' points customer table and time and label points transactions table.

```py
cutoff_times = pd.DataFrame()

cutoff_times['customer_id'] = es['customers'].df['customerno']

cutoff_times['time'] = es['transactions'].df['date']

cutoff_times['label'] = es['transactions'].df['action']
```

Comment: can you provide the output of `print(es)`, `print(es['transactions'])`, and  `print(es['customers'])`.  also, what is your target entity?

Comment: My target entity was customers and I changed it to transactions entity. modified `cutoff_times = es['transactions'].df[['id', 'date', 'action']].sort_values(by='date'). `Now it is working.